# How does Android Studio decompiles classes of included external library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a project in which i needed to edit some of the library files. But since i don't know how android studio decompiles the class files, it's hard for me to get the right code. I googled it but it refuses me. If anyone have any idea on that please help me.

Comment: what kind of library files you are trying to edit

Comment: its a jar file.

Comment: download the jar edit whatever you want and add it into gradle as dependency

Comment: how do i edit it? its already compiled. there is not java file there is only class files.

Comment: I mean download the jar from repo the source code if you have the compiled jar with no source code then  nothing can be done

Comment: ok thanks it solves my problem but how does android studio decompiles the class files? i am curious.